# Falling back to Parent Category if no asset exists

Tags: entries, assets, categories

I'm trying to make it so that if an entry image does not exist, then fall back to the category image that the entry belongs to. Right now this isn't working and is receiving an error.

```
{% set feature = entry.brandFeature.one() %}
{% set featureUrl = feature ? feature.url : entry.category.one().categoryImage.getUrl() %}
<div class="jumbotron category-jumbotron" style="background-image:url({{ featureUrl }})">
```

This is the error that craft is returning:

> Calling unknown method: craft\elements\db\AssetQuery::getUrl()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
entry.brandFeature.one()
```

Is correct, you'll access the asset field and execute the `one()` function in order to fetch the asset.

```
entry.category.one()
```

Is correct too. You'll **fetch** the first category of your categories field

```
entry.category.one().categoryImage
```

Will access the `categoryImage` asset field of your category.

But then you do

```
categoryImage.getUrl()
```

So you try to get the url from the field value but you don't actually grab the asset that might be stored in the category.

```
categoryImage.one().getUrl()
```

However - keep in mind there could be entries without a category. Then you'll receive an error as well.